# Connec pyqt signal with another class

Tags: python, pyqt

Is it possible for me to get pyqt signals to trigger a method from another class ? 
I've tried all sorts but with no luck.
My aim is to trigger the pickFile() method in the get_rooms when the room_file_button is clicked (marked).

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Protection
import xlrd
import csv
import os
import re 

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):    

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)


        self.room_file_button.clicked.connect(get_rooms.pickFile)   # this one
        self.radioButton_1.clicked.connect(self.onRadioButton1)       
        self.radioButton_2.clicked.connect(self.onRadioButton2)       
        self.radioButton_3.clicked.connect(self.onRadioButton3) 
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.valuechange)


class first_file(MyApp):            
    def __init__(self):
        MyApp.__init__(self)

        some methods .... 


class get_rooms(MyApp):

    def __init__(self):
        MyApp.__init__(self)

    def pickFile(self, value, group_1):
        print 'yipeee !'
        xy = 0
        while True:
            filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '.')
            if filename == '' and xy < 2:
                print(" ")
                xy = xy + 1
                continue
            elif filename != '':
                break
            else:
                sys.exit()
```

Comment: Why is are the classes `first_file` and `get_rooms` inheriting from `MyApp`? What do you want to achieve. Please give a little more information.

Answer (score -1):

At first, you can set `pickFile` function as static function (without self):

```
class get_rooms(MyApp):

    def __init__(self):
        MyApp.__init__(self)

    @staticmethod
    def pickFile(value, group_1):
```

and then you can use `room_file_button.clicked` signal; if you want to send parameters to that function, you can use `lambda`:

```
self.room_file_button.clicked.connect(lambda: get_rooms.pickFile(myValue,myGrupe))
```

Comment: You can create a instance of get_rooms and use the method as slot, too. So _you **must** set `pickFile` as static function_ is wrong! Also there will not be any arguments by call because the signal has no arguments defined. Lambda definition has no value.

Comment: Yes, **must** was wrong. I don't know about pyQt4, but in pyQt5 (and python 3) this code works correctly.

Comment: Maybe I should have stated im using PYQT4 and Python 2.7